# How to store complex JSON object in state and use it it render content in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm completely new to ReactJS and have been pulled in to do some work on it. I'm trying to store a complex JSON object in state and use data inside the complex object to render a component in UI. This is my code,

```
import { useState, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'reactstrap';
import axios from "axios";

export class Admin extends Component
{
    state = {
        excelData:{}
      }

    componentDidMount(){
           axios
            .get('https://reqres.in/api/unknown')
            .then((response) => { this.setState({...this.state, excelData: response.data})})
            
            console.log(this.state.excelData);
    }

    render(){
        return (
        <ListGroup>
           {
             this.state.excelData.data.map(name => <ListGroupItem>{name.name}</ListGroupItem>)
           }
         </ListGroup>
        )
    }
}
```

This is the JSON I'm trying to store,

```
{
   "page":1,
   "per_page":6,
   "total":12,
   "total_pages":2,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"cerulean",
         "year":2000,
         "color":"#98B2D1",
         "pantone_value":"15-4020"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"fuchsia rose",
         "year":2001,
         "color":"#C74375",
         "pantone_value":"17-2031"
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "name":"true red",
         "year":2002,
         "color":"#BF1932",
         "pantone_value":"19-1664"
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "name":"aqua sky",
         "year":2003,
         "color":"#7BC4C4",
         "pantone_value":"14-4811"
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "name":"tigerlily",
         "year":2004,
         "color":"#E2583E",
         "pantone_value":"17-1456"
      },
      {
         "id":6,
         "name":"blue turquoise",
         "year":2005,
         "color":"#53B0AE",
         "pantone_value":"15-5217"
      }
   ],
   "support":{
      "url":"https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
      "text":"To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
   }
}
```

What if I want to use both the `data` object from the above JSON and `support` object from the same JSON in different HTML elements? How do I achieve that?

I'm trying to store the entire data into excelData object and then use data inside my JSON object to load the listgroup. But it never works. It only works when I make my excelData into a collection and read the data object directly in my API call. Please help.

Comment: Can you share an example response? Is it intentional that you’re calling “data.data” on “response” in excelData.data  - or did you forget that you already dug into “data” when setting state?

Comment: I recommend adding in more details so it's easier to help. "It never works" - do you get an error message? What happens? How are you converting it to a collection and reading it directly? What's unacceptable about the solution you found?

Comment: response.data is the entire JSON returned by the API. But the actual data I want is nested inside the complex JSON and it's called data. So basically if I set my state as response.data.data, then my list group loads. But I need the entire JSON in my state as I want to use the other parts of the JSON for other uses. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount(){
       axios
        .get('https://reqres.in/api/unknown')
        .then((response) => { this.setState({...this.state, {...response.data} })})
        
        console.log(this.state.excelData);
}
```

this way you can access your excel data via

```
this.state.data
```

and others like:

```
this.state.support
```

you may need null checks so be careful.